# A shape where every point is a saddle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

Is there a shape / surface for which every point is a saddle point?

Thanks.

Comment: Any kind of curvature leads to non-saddle points so I am assuming that only (hyper)planes satisfy your request.

Comment: A horizontal plane, depending on your definition.

Comment: A saddle has partial derivatives $0$, so if every point is a saddle point, all derivatives vanish. So it is a plane, but points on planes are not normally considered saddle points, so there is no such surface. On the other hand you might be interested in the pseudosphere, which has constant curvature of $-1$, just like the curvature at a saddle point.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Ahh, the pseudosphere is interesting. Would a hyperbolic plane also not satisfy the requirements as it also has constant negative curvature of -1?

Comment: Gauss curvature negative surfaces have saddle points everywhere.  Converse need not be true. Both Poincare hyperbolic models are flat models.

Comment: @ThomasMoore: yes the hyperbolic plane has constant negative curvature. I didn't mention it since it is not embeddable in 3 dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

$$  x^2 + y^2 = \cosh^2 z   $$